# Ubuntu 20.04.3 Server - Only Able to Open One Terminal

Tags: command-line, 20.04

After an update about two weeks ago, I am only able to access one terminal. Ctrl-Alt-F(pick a number) i am unable to start another terminal. Has anyone come across this issue? I have Google'd it but unable to come up with a resolution. This is at the server console.

The `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` file has not been modified from its default:

```
[Login]
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
#HandleSuspendKey=suspend
#HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
#HandleLidSwitch=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
#RuntimeDirectorySize=10%
#RemoveIPC=yes
#InhibitorsMax=8192
#SessionsMax=8192
```

Comment: I never knew of `Ctrl-Alt-FN` and have only ever used `Alt-FN`, but anyway both work for me, but it does take awhile before the login prompt (about 5 seconds). For hardware reasons, I have to use the HWE stack, so kernel: `Linux s19 5.11.0-41-generic #45~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 10 10:20:10 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

Comment: I assume `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` is unchanged with the default `#NAutoVTs=6`

Comment: I verified it: [Login]
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
#HandleSuspendKey=suspend
#HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
#HandleLidSwitch=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
#RuntimeDirectorySize=10%
#RemoveIPC=yes
#InhibitorsMax=8192
#SessionsMax=8192

Comment: Which kernel version? Have you tried booting to a previous kernel?

Comment: 5.4.0-91-generic

Comment: Try my oldest kernel

Comment: I tried kernel 5.4.0-91-generic. It worked fine.

Comment: It did not work

Comment: I wiped the server (Ubuntu 20.04) and reinstall Ubuntu 20.04.3 on the server console i can still only open one tty (tty1)